# Multi-lenguaje utilizando laravel y vue

Tags: php, laravel, session

Estoy desarrollando una pagina la cual va a tener multi-idioma **español** y  **ingles**, para el `front-end` estoy utilizando `vue-i18n`. En el `front-end` envio el idioma activo cada vez que necesito algun dato del `back-end`

El problema

Cuando elijo el idioma, envio al `back-end` el idioma seleccionado, luego lo guardo en la `sesion`, pero cuando necesito que `laravel` devuelva un mensaje en el idioma seleccionado, este lo devuelve en español (idioma por defecto).
Intente esto en el `AppServiceProvider`

```
app()->setLocale(session()->has('lang') ? session()->get('lang') : 'es');
```

cuando reviso la sesion arroja `null`.

cuando guardo la sesion la guardo asi

```
session()->put('lang', $request->input('lang'));
// o
session(['lang' => $request->input('lang')]);
    return response()->json([
        'lang' => app()->getLocale()
]);
```

por que la sesion no se esta guardando? intente utilizando `cookie` o `file` en el driver y el problema persiste.